# Erro ao adicionar dados no banco de dados

Tags: c#

Estou tendo dificuldades para inserir as informações com parâmetros:

```
private static void InsereNovoMenuParaOUsuario(int idAcao, DTO.ModulosProgramaAcoes acao)
{
    using (var conn =  Conexao.ConectaDb()) {
        var listUser = new List<DTO.ModulosMenuAcessoUser>();

        var cmd = new SqlCommand
        {
            Connection = conn,
            CommandType = CommandType.Text,
            CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT idUser FROM ModulosMenuAcessoUser"
        };

        conn.Open();

        var adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        var dt = new DataTable();
        adap.Fill(dt);


        for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var user = new DTO.ModulosMenuAcessoUser()
            {
                IdUser = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["idUser"]),
                IdModulo = acao.IdModulo,
                IdPrograma = acao.IdPrograma,
                IdAcao = idAcao
            };

            listUser.Add(user);
        }

        foreach (var acesso in listUser)
        {

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT ModulosMenuAcessoUser(IdModulo,IdPrograma,IdAcoes,IdUser)" + Environment.NewLine +
                               "VALUES " + Environment.NewLine +
                               "(@IdModulo,@IdPrograma,@IdAcoes,@IdUser)";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IdUser", SqlDbType.Int).Value = acesso.IdUser;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IdModulo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = acesso.IdModulo;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IdPrograma", SqlDbType.Int).Value = acesso.IdPrograma;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IdAcoes", SqlDbType.Int).Value = acesso.IdAcao;

        }

        var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
        cmd.Transaction = transaction;

        try {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.Rollback();
            throw e;
        }

    }
}
```

exibe o seguinte erro:

> e={"O nome da variável '@IdUser' já foi declarado. Os nomes de
>   variáveis devem ser exclusivos em um lote de consultas ou em um
>   procedimento armazenado."}

Comment: É isso que está falando e com o que você postou não temos como saber. Dá pra ver que tem outros problemas no código, que deixam ele funcionar, mas não está certo.

Comment: @AndreAndriotti, como não tenho certeza do problema, fiz uma alteração no código e joguei em 1 notepad online, não é de praxe fazermos isso, mas você poderia testar o código, por favor? Caso resolva postarei como solução, segue o link: https://www.invertexto.com/zjmk72

Comment: O problema acontece porque já existe um parâmetro com esse nome `@IdUser` e consequentemente os outros devem aparecer esse problema. Pra resolver coloque um `cmd.Parameters.Clear()` antes da primeira linha do `cmd.Parameters.Add("@IdUser", SqlDbType.Int).Value = acesso.IdUser;` já vai funcionar, claro o seu código pode ser melhorado.

Answer (score 0):

Apesar de ter passado já muito tempo... está aí a resolução:

Como você está utilizando:

cmd.Parameters.Add("@IdPrograma", SqlDbType.Int).Value = acesso.IdPrograma;

Para adicionar os parâmetros no insert, caso seja feito uma só inserção ocorre tudo bem, porem com o mesmo parametro já não consegue "Add", então deve ser feito a limpeza destes dados antes de inserir novamente utilizando:

cmd.Parameters.Clear();

Lembrando: Deve utilizar esse comando após a execução do insert